# Spring boot Elasticsearch: Geo Point not creating correct mapping. Fails on searching

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch for Geo searches. 
I have written code to generate random points (lat-lng) within a limit from a centre point. This is inserted into an index, on which the search happens later on.

Versions:

- Spring Boot: **2.2.1.RELEASE**
- Spring Data Elastic Search: (spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch) **2.2.1.RELEASE**
- ElasticSearch: org.elasticsearch : **6.8.4**

pom.xml

```
        <parent>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
           <relativePath/>
        </parent>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
          <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
          <version>6.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Elastic Configuration:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.RestClients;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "elastic")
@Configuration
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class EsBeanConfig {

  private String host;
  private String port;

  @Bean
  public RestHighLevelClient client() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
        .connectedTo(host + ":" + port)
        .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
  }

  @Bean(name = "elasticsearchRestTemplate")
  public ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchRestTemplate() {
    return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
  }

}
```

Elastic entity:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.GeoPointField;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint;


@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Document(indexName = "geo_location_index", type = "geo-class-point-type", replicas = 0, shards = 1)
public class EsGeoPointEntity {

  @Id
  @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
  private String id;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
  private String storeName;

  @GeoPointField
  private GeoPoint geoPoint;

}
```

Index Creation: This creates the index, which is causing issue as it does not create geo_point type.

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    AnnotatedTypeScanner scanner = new AnnotatedTypeScanner(false, Document.class);
    for (Class clazz : scanner.findTypes("com.geohash.entity.elastic")) {
      Document doc = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, Document.class);
      assert doc != null;
      if (!elasticsearchRestTemplate.indexExists(doc.indexName())) {
        log.info("Index - {} does not exists. Creating index now!!", doc.indexName());
        elasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndex(clazz); 
   //     elasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndex(doc.indexName()); --> Not using
      }
      elasticsearchRestTemplate.refresh(doc.indexName());
    }
  }
```

Elasticsearch's index mapping looks like this: [location is not of geo_point type]

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "geo-class-point-type": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "properties": {
            "lat": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "lon": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        },
        "storeName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code to add a random location: I am generating random lat and lng values, and adding to index using GeoPoint.

```
  private EsGeoPointEntity location(String namePrefix, LatLong latLong,
      double radius) {
    EsGeoPointEntity esGeoPointEntity = new EsGeoPointEntity();
    String id = UUIDs.base64UUID();
    esGeoPointEntity.setId(id);
    esGeoPointEntity.setStoreName(namePrefix + id);
    esGeoPointEntity.setLocation(
        new GeoPoint(latLong.getLatitude().doubleValue(), latLong.getLongitude().doubleValue()));

    return esGeoPointEntity;
  }
```

Code to Insert data:

```
@Override
  public void bulkIndex(List<?> objects) {
    try {
      List<IndexQuery> queries = new ArrayList<>();
      Class<?> clazz = objects.get(0).getClass();
      Document doc = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, Document.class);
      String idMethodName = ApplicationUtils.getIdMethodName(clazz);
      assert doc != null;
      log.debug("index Name {} and index type {}", doc.indexName(), doc.type());
      for (Object obj : objects) {
        IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQuery();
        // Getting the ID
        indexQuery.setId(String.valueOf(ApplicationUtils.getProperty(obj, idMethodName)));
        indexQuery.setObject(obj);
        indexQuery.setIndexName(doc.indexName());
        indexQuery.setType(doc.type());
        queries.add(indexQuery);
      }
      if (!queries.isEmpty()) {
        elasticsearchRestTemplate.bulkIndex(queries);
        elasticsearchRestTemplate.refresh(doc.indexName());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error while bulk Indexing.", e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

To find the number of location within a specified radius and a Geo Point, I'm using the below code:

```
  @Override
  public List<EsGeoPointEntity> findLocationWithinDistance(double latitude, double longitude,
      double distance) {
    try {
      CriteriaQuery geoLocationCriteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(
          new Criteria("geoPoint").within(
              new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), distance + "km"));

      return elasticsearchRestTemplate
          .queryForList(geoLocationCriteriaQuery, EsGeoPointEntity.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error while fetching nearby locations.", e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Error while fetching nearby locations:

```
2019-12-04 20:45:05.911 ERROR 51726 [http-nio-7676-exec-3] --- j.c.r.g.s.e.impl.EsIndexerServiceImpl    Line: (92): Error while fetching nearby locations.
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2053)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2030)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1777)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1696)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:1092)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForPage(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:511)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForList(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:457)
    at com.geohash.service.elastic.impl.EsIndexerServiceImpl.findLocationWithinDistance(EsIndexerServiceImpl.java:90)
    at com.service.elastic.impl.EsLocationGenerationServiceImpl.findLocationWithinDistance(EsLocationGenerationServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.geohash.controller.EsLocationController.findLocationWithinDistance(EsLocationController.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/geo_location_index/geo-class-point-type/_search?rest_total_hits_as_int=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to find geo_point field [geoPoint]","index_uuid":"xlQjtUmqTMiGsyGcZj9HGw","index":"geo_location_index"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"dfs","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"geo_location_index","node":"hWqt86GoQJqJGovxnpqQRg","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to find geo_point field [geoPoint]","index_uuid":"xlQjtUmqTMiGsyGcZj9HGw","index":"geo_location_index"}}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:936)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:233)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1764)
        ... 64 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/geo_location_index/geo-class-point-type/_search?rest_total_hits_as_int=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to find geo_point field [geoPoint]","index_uuid":"xlQjtUmqTMiGsyGcZj9HGw","index":"geo_location_index"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"dfs","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"geo_location_index","node":"hWqt86GoQJqJGovxnpqQRg","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to find geo_point field [geoPoint]","index_uuid":"xlQjtUmqTMiGsyGcZj9HGw","index":"geo_location_index"}}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:552)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:537)
        at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalRequestExecutor.inputReady(InternalRequestExecutor.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

PS: I have also tried this with, but same issue:

- Elasticsearch: 6.4.3
- Transport client: 6.4.3
- Spring Data Elasticsearch: 3.1.10.RELEASE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! I did miss a crucial information and by adding one small line of code, it worked.

Here goes: **For Geo types, dynamic mapping will not work.** So, enforce a mapping through code before any data gets inserted or create a mapping manually in ES.

I added the code in my `@PostConstruct`:

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    AnnotatedTypeScanner scanner = new AnnotatedTypeScanner(false, Document.class);
    for (Class clazz : scanner.findTypes("com.geohash.entity.elastic")) {
      Document doc = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, Document.class);
      assert doc != null;
      if (!elasticsearchRestTemplate.indexExists(doc.indexName())) {
        log.info("Index - {} does not exists. Creating index now!!", doc.indexName());
        elasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndex(clazz);
      }
      elasticsearchRestTemplate.refresh(doc.indexName());

      elasticsearchRestTemplate.putMapping(clazz);  --> Saviour
    }
  }
```

The mapping, thus created, is correct and has **geo_point**.

**NOTE**: *Did not find this in the documentation*.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. The solution works, only thing I couldn't do was do was .refresh(do.indexName()), but it's possible elasticsearchRestTemplate.refresh(clazz);